# user inputs not show in database table?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, while-loop, user-input

I'm trying to teach myself java(my English is not good sorry). after giving some inputs I tried to show(the values using select * from emp;) it on the table but rows are not creating what should I do to get the user input to (database)

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
    Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
    Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE","system","manager");
    
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement= connection.prepareStatement("insert into emp values(?,?,?)" );
    
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    while (true) {
        
        System.out.println("enter eid");
        int eid = scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.println("enter ename");
        String ename = scanner.next();
        System.out.println("enter esal");
        double esal = scanner.nextDouble();
        
        preparedStatement.setInt(1, eid);
        preparedStatement.setString(2, ename);
        preparedStatement.setDouble(3, esal);
        System.out.println("data insert successfull....do you want add one more recored(yes/no)");
        String option = scanner.next();
        
        
        if(option.equals("no")) 
            break;
        
    }
    
       scanner.close();
       preparedStatement.close();
       connection.close();
       System.out.println("resource are closed");
    
}
```

}

Comment: Make sure you `COMMIT` the data. This should occur automatically when the transaction is closed but your JDBC connection may be set to have auto-commit mode as False; in which case you will need to manually `COMMIT`.

Comment: With your latest update, you never execute the statement, so nothing ends up in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 3 different JDBC execute functions:

- `PreparedStatement.execute` is for executing any statement; including DDL statements such as `CREATE TABLE`, etc.
- `PreparedStatement.executeQuery` is for executing `SELECT` statements.
- `PreparedStatement.executeUpdate` is for executing DML statements such as `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE` or `MERGE`.

You want `PreparedStatement.executeUpdate` and not `PreparedStatement.executeQuery`.

You also need to check that your statement/transaction is committing the data; if it is not then you need to explicitly `COMMIT` the data.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is on `ResultSet resultSet=preparedStatement.executeQuery();` executeQuery() is only for selects if you want to insert so you must use `preparedStatement.execute();` or `preparedStatement.executeUpdate();`

Answer (score 0):

For inserts and deletion, it should be executeUpdate().

> ResultSet resultSet = preparedStarement.executeUpdate();